# Using nnndpi for Android layout folders

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After years of work with Android layouts that are pixel specific, I came across the "nnndpi" qualifier.  I haven't been able to specifically target the Samsung Galaxy S8 to separate it from other devices pulling from the sw360dp-xxxhdpi folder.  The sw360dp-xxxhdpi also targets the S7 so the two devices actually show certain screen elements as about 60dp off when defining marginLeft in the xml file.

I tried to define h740dp and h740dp-xxxhdpi, 568dpi, 142dpi, and a few other variations I came up with from this great device spec resource: https://material.io/tools/devices

I haven't been able to target the S8 and think there has to be a way to target this specific device and any other device on the market (regardless of whether that's a bad design practice).

Comment: You're not supposed to make layouts to target specific devices. The classifications are there to make layouts work on general device specifications. You should be using `dp` values for your dimensions, not `px.

Comment: @TheWanderer I'm aware that's not the best design practice as I stated in the question, just wanted to know how to use the nnndpi qualifier since it is given to us by Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S8 screen is 360dp x 740dp at xxxhdpi. The resource qualifiers that you could use to target this screen are:

- `sw360dp` (smallest width) - The S8 will match this always
- `w360dp` (available width) - The S8 will match this regardless of orientation (since it will have much more than 360dp of width in landscape)
- `h740dp` (available height) - The S8 will match this in portrait (though not exactly; see more below)
- `xxxhdpi` (pixel density) - The S8 will match this always

The problem with the `h740dp` qualifier is that the "available width/height" qualifiers don't give you the physical screen size; they subtract for persistent UI like the status bar and the navigation bar. The status bar is usually 24dp and the navigation bar is larger (often 48dp or more), but neither of these is guaranteed (and if you use `fitsSystemWindows` or otherwise hide these bars then you can get different results).

On top of that, any "targeting" you do based on screen size will always have the potential to target other devices, since nothing is stopping LG from creating a phone with an xxxhdpi screen that's at least 360x740dp.

Together, that means that you shouldn't do what you're doing. But if you must do it, then I would try this set of qualifiers: `layout-sw360dp-h668dp-xxxhdpi` for portrait (you can experiment with the exact number to use for `hXXXdp` to account for the status and navigation bars) and `layout-sw360dp-w740dp-xxxhdpi` for landscape.

Comment: What a great answer...good luck finding that layout folder syntax on the web besides here!  I did try layout-h740dp-land-xxxhdpi.. Trying this now

Comment: After some testing, layout-sw360dp-w668dp-xxxhdpi worked!  I thought at least one of those were wrong since you wrote layout-sw360dp-h668dp-xxxhdpi in your answer.. one would think that sw and w in the name would cancel out or cause an error... wild cool answer my friend.. changes everything for targeting specific devices

Comment: layout-h740dp didn't wok for galaxy s8

Comment: @jairhumberto see my explanation in the answer; you'll have to subtract something like 72dp or more in order to compensate for the status and navigation bars.

Comment: @BenP. unexpected solution! I'm having a similar problem, the layout on 16:9 xxxhdpi devices is fine, but on 18:9 xxxhdpi devices is not. The latter is an LG G6. Any guesses how to target that screen size specifically (1440 x 2880). I tried with nnndpi (layout-564dpi) and with layout-sw360dp-h2802dp-xxxhdpi (trying to follow your instructions), but I'm not succeeding. Any ideas?

Comment: @Eir Assuming the density is 3.5, a 1440x2880 screen will be 411x822 `dp`. So you could try `layout-sw411dp-h750-xxxhdpi`. The smallest width is `411` because it's always 411dp wide (at least), and the available height is `750` because that's 822 minus 24 for the status bar and minus 48 for the nav bar.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks a lot! Not catching it still... How do you figure out the density? The specs say: 5.7" (1440 x 2880) QHD+ FullVision® IPS Quantum Display, and additionally: 18:9 ratio (~564 ppi density). If you have any advise in which direction I could keep trying, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: The density value I mentioned is taken by dividing the real pixel density by 160. If the ppi for your screen is 564, then `564/160 = 3.525`. Then you can compute the `dp` dimensions by dividing the pixel dimensions by this value, so `1440/3.525=408.51` (so probably rounded to 408 or 409dp). **However**, the _real_ pixel density of the device (564 for you) is often _not_ what Android uses for its math... get a `DisplayMetrics` instance and check what the `density` is listed as. _That's_ the real number Android uses for its math.

Comment: @BenP. Thanks! I'm not there, yet. I see these values: [density=4.0, densityDpi=640, heightPirxels=2672, noncompatDensity=4.0, noncompatDensityDpi=640, noncompatHeightPixels=2672, noncompatScaledDensity=4.0, noncompatWidthPixels=1440, noncompatXdpi=562.707, noncompatYdpi=562.707, scaledDensity=4.0, widthPixels=1440, xdpi=562.707, ydpi=562.707]. So, I tried `layout-sw360dp-h648dp-xxxhdpi` and it didn't work. If it is obvious for you what the magic formula would be, please let me know. Otherwise, I'll try to get my head around this tomorrow.

Comment: So, the dpi value is `640`, the width is `1440px`, and the height is `2672px`. `640/160 = 4`, so the width is `1440px / 4 = 360dp` and the height is `668dp`. All together, that would give you `layout-sw360dp-h668dp-xxxhdpi`... but what you had should work too, so I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: @BenP. I just wanted to post the epilogue. I ended up rendering the layout in an image. It is a specific part of my app that can handle that. Much easier and much better results.